# How can I remove unused indexes in Google Application Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing

I've [accidentally added](http://adventuresinthecloud.blogspot.com/2009/05/building-app-engine-google-query-terror.html) a new filter to my GAE application. The status of the index is 'serving' now - however I don't need that index at all and I'd like to remove. How can I do that?

Comment: Would be awesome if you could delete these with the browser console =(

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/indexconfig):

> **Deleting Unused Indexes**
>
> When you change or remove an index
> from index.yaml, the original index is
> not deleted from App Engine
> automatically. This gives you the
> opportunity to leave an older version
> of the app running while new indexes
> are being built, or to revert to the
> older version immediately if a problem
> is discovered with a newer version.
>
> When you are sure that old indexes are
> no longer needed, you can delete them
> from App Engine using the following
> command:
>
> ```
> appcfg.py vacuum_indexes myapp/
> ```
>
> This command deletes all indexes for the app that are not mentioned in the local version of index.yaml.

Comment: @fuentesjr: I took the liberty of adding the quoted text/code to your post.

Comment: This seams to work for the Python version only :-( When using the JavaSDK the vacuum_indexes parameter is missing. It's also no use using the appcfg.py command, for Java does not store the indexes in index.yaml Which means you would have to create this file yourself and try to type all the indexes within the way you defined them in Javas xml.

Comment: If I remove an index from index.yaml will GAE continue to create this index or I have to delete it with the mentioned process?

Answer (score 26):

For GAE / Java, the documentation includes [this information](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Deleting_Unused_Indexes):

> **Deleting Unused Indexes**
>
> ...
>
> When you are sure that old indexes are no longer needed, you can
>   delete them from App Engine using the vacuum_indexes action:
>
> ```
> ./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh vacuum_indexes myapp/war
> ```
>
> This command deletes all indexes for the app that are not mentioned in
>   the local versions of datastore-indexes.xml and
>   generated/datastore-indexes-auto.xml.

Comment: WARNING: For me, it only seemed to take datastore-indexes-auto.xml into consideration. This meant it offered to delete indexes that were mentioned in datastore-indexes.xml claiming they were no longer used (when they were). Apart from that though, it worked for me in deleting my error indexes and I didn't have to create any yaml files like other answers suggest.

Comment: I'm on Windows and I used the "appcfg.cmd vacuum_indexes c:\myappdir\war" with success.  It kicked off my Web browser to do the authentication.  Had to paste in a code.

Comment: If you get a "Either the access code is invalid or the OAuth token is revoked.Details: invalid_grant" type of error try deleting the ".appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java" file in your user directory.

Answer (score 7):

As of Feb 2019 it's now:

```
gcloud datastore indexes cleanup index.yaml
```

Answer (score 5):

In **Windows Google AppEngine Java**, we have to use **appcfg.cmd** command to **delete unused indexes** of deployed application.

**Syntax :**

> appengine-java-sdk-path\bin\appcfg.cmd vacuum_indexes project-root-path\poject-name\war\

Answer (score 4):

For gae-java, as JochenJung mentioned, the "vacuum_indexes" tool will work, but you'll have to emulate a python project in the following way:

Note that the vacuum tool seems only to work when pointed at *.appspot.com, not the local dev. environment.

- create app.yaml for your app and put this in your /myapp/ root directory, minimally:

```
    application: myproj
    version: 4
    runtime: python
    api_version: 1
```

where "version" is your app's version, "myproj" the GAE name of your project.

- create an index.yaml and put it in the same root dir. Instead of laboriously putting into that file the index information for indices you want to keep, it turns out that the tool is going to give you a yes/no confirmation for each and every index it deletes, so it is simpler just to indicate that ALL indices should be dropped, and use the confirmation to preserve the ones you want to keep.

```
indexes:

# AUTOGENERATED
```

Then run the command as shown above,

```
  /appcfg.py vacuum_indexes /path/to/myproj/
```

Comment: I'm using Java GAE. This worked like a charm.

However, I did have to update the `app.yaml` to something like:


    `application: myproj
    version: 4
    runtime: python
    api_version: 1

    handlers:
    -url: /
     script: home.py` 
since I was getting an error `No UrlMap entires found in application configuration` when running `vaccum_indexes`. Also, just to make it clear, both the `app.yaml` and `index.yaml` file should go inside your `war/WEB-INF` folder. Then the command to run, as an example, would be: `appcfg.py vacuum_indexes /path/to/myproj/WEB-INF`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using **maven** `mvn appengine:vacuum_indexes`. No need to `mvn appengine:update`, the command updates the remote server.

A full list of maven commands [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven).

Answer (score 2):

On Windows using Java, this command worked for me:

```
appcfg.cmd vacuum_indexes C:\Users\Name\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\backend\src\main\webapp\
```

**Note:** Make sure you have a `datastore-indexes.xml` in the `webapp` folder (these indexes will be spared).

Answer (score 2):

With the current version of gcloud, you can simply do:

```
gcloud datastore cleanup-indexes index.yaml
```

which is more intuitive than calling appcfg.cmd [...].

Answer (score 1):

`gcloud datastore cleanup-indexes /path/to/file/index.yaml`

this command **no longer works**.

`gcloud datastore indexes cleanup /path/to/index.yaml`

this is the **new command**.

you should run them in `google cloud console`. normally you can upload the `index.yaml` file using `file upload` feature in `google cloud console`. your file goes to a directly called `_admin` you can `cd` to there and call,

`gcloud datastore indexes cleanup index.yaml`

#### Tip

if you are using `datastore` in a **java project**, you have `datastore-indexes.xml` instead of `index.yaml`. You might have some trouble finding the `index.yaml` file if you don't know where to look.

you can simply find the path of the `index.yaml` file by looking at the `deploy console` in your IDE.

Comment: For Java projects: They do not maintain an index.yaml file and `gcloud datastore indexes cleanup` does not process datastore-indexes.xml files. To bridge this gap, I converted datastore-indexes.xml to index.yaml using: 
`gcloud beta app migrate-config datastore-indexes-xml-to-yaml <path to datastore-indexes.xml>`
This does not switch Java projects to using index.yaml, i.e. needs to be repeated before attempting to clean up datastore indexes