# HRD migration broke datastore queries & indexes

Tags: google-app-engine, migration, database-migration

Google appengine HRD migration has been a nightmare for me. I migrated my 55GB datastore to HRD yesterday. Since then many queries and indexes are broken:

**Some examples**:

- Select * from table1 where col1=val1  => query.get() returns empty in
  python. However, it works in datastore viewer.
- Select * from table1
  where col1=val1  => query.count()>0. However query.get() = empty.
- Select * from table1 where col1=val1 order by col2 desc => Almost
  half of the rows are getting missed in the response. Same behavior in
  datastore viewer.

How do I get these tables and indexes repaired? Any way of getting Google Appengine team support for addressing this issue? Its a GAE Migration tool bug.

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables get repaired automatically in about 2-3 days. Thats a HRD problem. My problem is now resolved.

Answer (score 4):

When the migration tool is used, a new app id is assigned, which makes all the keys change.

To recreate the custom indexes:

1. Temporarily empty index.yaml.
2. Vacuum the indexes (check out [How can I remove unused indexes in Google Application Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813839/how-can-i-remove-unused-indexes-in-google-application-engine) for further information).
3. **Wait until all the indexes have been deleted.**
4. Restore index.yaml.
5. Create indexes by either redeploying the application or running `appcfg.py update_indexes <path>` (check out [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Updating_Indexes) for furher information).

You may also need to manually update all of the other references (e.g. a ListProperty of keys) if you have any.

**Edit**
The simple, mono-property indexes that are managed automatically by App Engine are created/updated when a property is put.
To regenerate them, I recommend creating and running a simple MapReduce task to put every existing entity. This procedure should rebuild *all* the indexes (including those defined in index.yaml).
As this is a costly process, first do it manually with a few entities to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: I do not have any index in index.yaml for the first two examples above.

Comment: @SaurabhSahni sorry for leaving that out. I've updated my answer with information as to the automatic indexes. Please check if it helps and let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you. But, thats going to be lot of work! Any way of getting Google Appengine team support for addressing this issue? Its a GAE Migration tool bug.

Comment: It's not really much work. You can download [the mapreduce library](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) and get it done in a few lines of code. However, it will take a long time and will certainly cost you a lot. [Try filing a production issue.](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry)

Comment: Thanks, this saved my server. I started copying data before deploying to the new instance and my indexes were broken. I have fixed them by using this answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Update : finally it fix itself in 24 hours=)**

I have the same problem as you

query.count()>0. However query.get() or fetch() is empty.

Its strange that some table work fine but some table has this problem

**I think it is Google App Engine problem from migration very large table(model).**

I hope my tables will recovered like yours in 2-3 days too.